# Mac PackageMaker - Allow Relocation Issues

Tags: macos, installation, packagemaker

I have two issues with Allow Relocation (Package: Xxx, Components):

1. It keeps getting turned on as if by magic. How can I avoid this? I need it off (sub-optimal, I know - see #2)
2. If Allow Relocation is on, the Installer first places the .app into /Applications, but then relocates it, copying it on top of my original .app in my development tree. How can I prevent this from happening during development, short of testing the installer on a different machine?

Comment: Do you mean that your development tree is in /Applications?  Otherwise I don't see the danger in putting it there first (other than the annoyance of needing the space whether it's ending there or not)

Comment: I have the same problem.  Test installs go into the dev tree every time because relocation settings get changed as the result of touching almost any other setting in PackageMaker.  

I'm sure you've come across the many and varied suggestions for working around this in your searches.  The only thing that worked reliably for me was to manually re-check that relocate setting in every package's components tab as the last thing before a build.

Comment: Is there any news? I have the same issue, but I can't check this option every time because I run the PackageMake from command line..

Answer (score 3):

PackageMaker manpage says

```
 [--no-relocate, -w]
          If specified, packagemaker will disable automatic relocation of
          package contents.
```

Answer (score 0):

In PackageMaker 3, relocation is enabled by default. However, there are ways to disable it.
If you are using GUI mode, just uncheck the checkbox `"Allow Relocation"`.
If you are using command-line build, use the flags `--no-relocate` or `-w` as mentioned in PackageMaker man page.